Solve $\left||x^2-3x+2| + |x+5|\right| > |x^2-2x+7|$ using the triangle inequality.
Perhaps I was incorrect, but I was under the impression that the triangle inequality (pictured below) would work as setting the first modulus as an $a$ and the second as a $b$, and the less than as $a+b$. Thus, seeing as how they are
$$
|a|+|b|>|a+b|
$$
we would use $ab>0$, meaning that $x\in(-5,1)\cup(2,\infty)$. However, double checking with the standard procedure of setting cases, the answer we are supposed to achieve through the triangle inequality is $x\in(-\infty, -5)\cup(1,2)$, which is what we would achieve if we were to set $ab<0$. Is there something I am misunderstanding here?


I am new to the stack overflower mathematics forum, I have gone over the guidelines but if there is something that is needed to change in my post I will gladly change it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm asking for clarification on what exactly I did wrong in my method on applying the triangle inequality, i.e why $ab<0$ is applicible here and not $ab>0$

Why taking the absolute value of $x^2-2x+7$ when this is always positive? :-)

The question just asks me to solve it with the triangle inequality, it's probably just added for clarification

We have that $|a|+|b|\ge |a+b|$ therefore
$$|x^2-3x+2| + |x+5| \ge |x^2-2x+7|$$
is always true and since LHS is not negative we have $$|x^2-3x+2| + |x+5|=||x^2-3x+2| + |x+5||\ge |x^2-2x+7|$$
And now we need to exclude the equality case, that is
$$|x^2-3x+2| + |x+5| = |x^2-2x+7|$$
which holds when both $x^2-3x+2$ and $x+5$ are not negative, since $x^2-2x+7>0$ and leads to $x\in[-5,1]\cup[2,\infty)$, so solution is $x\in(-\infty, -5)\cup(1,2)$.
